# Display all the child values in a single row with , separated which has same parent id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want a simple sql script for the following requirement. And the data may increase in future and it is not static. So I need dynamic query. Someone please help me with this.

I have a data like this

[image: input]

and the output should be like this.

[image: output]

Comment: MySql and Sql Server are very different database engines that will solve this particular problem in very different ways. Which one are you using? Also, it's considered very rude here to post links or images of your sample data and output, rather than the text. It also makes it less likely for you to get an answer, because not everyone will see your images. Finally, what you're asking to do is considered poor practice for a relational database. Relational databases deal in records; applications can roll up the csv data when they need it.

Comment: Hey Joel, Thanks for your reply. Firstly I'm using SQL. I need SQL code. And reg the images, I'm pretty new posting questions here. I do not know how to display my data in table format. Hence I used the images.

Comment: **Which** Sql? There is more than one dialect, and the answer to your question depends greatly on which dialect you need (MySql uses group_concat() while Sql Server 2008 and later can use Stuff() ). For the data... do your best. We can help edit the formatting, but image is **always** worse in this context.

Comment: Thanks Joel for helping me in formatting.

Comment: @Akhil post your code,input,required output,sample data as text .and also mention your db engine clearly on what you are woring .here is a guide for [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The formatting is still broken. I've bookmarked the question, and I'll check back in about 10 minutes. If there's still no clear database engine in the question at that time I'll have to downvote and vote to close the question as unclear.

Comment: @Mahesh.K - Thanks for the guide. I'll follow this guide for my next question. I'm using MS SQL 2014.

Comment: @Akhil My please to help you .happy coding -:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using  Stuff() in MSSql server

```
;With cte(ParentId, ChidId)
    AS
    (
    SELECT 1,'a'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'b'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'123'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'asd'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'222'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'kk'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'ffh'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'aaa'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'fdhgf' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'fdddv'
    )
    SELECT parentid, 
           Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + chidid 
                  FROM   cte i 
                  WHERE  i.parentid = o.parentid 
                  FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') AS ChidId 
    FROM   cte o 
    GROUP  BY parentid
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Srini131. But my data is dynamic.

Comment: Did you save data in Physical table right ? If so replace Cte with your physical table name the query will work

Comment: Thanks @Srini131. Got it